# Prove that if $ 2^n $ divides $ 3^m-1 $ then $ 2^{n-2} $ divides $ m $

Tags: elementary-number-theory, arithmetic

I got a difficult problem. It's kind of difficult to prove. Can you do it?

Let $ m,n\geq 3 $ be two positive integers. Prove that if $ 2^n $ divides $ 3^m -1$ then $ 2^{n-2} $ divides $ m $

Thanks :-)

Comment: What attempt have you made?

Comment: $2^n$ does *not* divide $3^m$ if $m$ and $n$ are positive integers.

Comment: Note that the statement, "If I can fly, then pigs are green" is true as a statement.

Comment: Did you mean $3^m-1$?

Comment: There was a big mistake :) It's $3^m-1$, not $3^m$

Answer (score 4):

This statement is a **vacuous truth**, meaning that the condition $3^m \equiv 0 \mod{2^n}$ is never satisfied.

Comment: Indeed, if $2^n$ divides $3^m$ then the moon is made of cheese.

Comment: I've corrected it

Comment: @Jax I think that after the original question has been answered the correct thing to do is to post a new question.

Comment: Thanks. I'm gonna delete it and I'll post a new one

Comment: @Jax By "post a new one" did you mean you would edit the existing question? It seems that's what you did. Now you have two good answers for the intended question, so you might as well accept one. At this point, I'm not sure posting a new question is a good idea any more. It might have been OK if you had actually done it the way you said.

Answer (score 1):

Because $n \geq 3$ we get $8 \mid 3^m-1$ and so $m$ must be even .

Let $m=2^l \cdot k$ with $k$ odd . Now use the difference of squares repeatedly to get :

$$3^m-1=(3^k-1)(3^k+1)(3^{2k}+1)\cdot \ldots \cdot (3^{2^{k-1} \cdot l}+1)$$

Each term of the form $3^s+1$ with $s$ even has the power of $2$ in their prime factorization exactly $1$ because: $$3^s+1 \equiv 1+1\equiv 2 \pmod{8}$$

Also $k$ is odd so :

$$3^k+1 \equiv 3+1 \equiv 4  \pmod{8}$$ has two factors of $2$ .

Finally the term $3^k-1 \equiv 3-1 \equiv 2 \pmod{8}$ has one factor of $2$ .

This means that $3^m-1$ has $1+2+l-1=l+2$ two's in his prime factorization .

But $2^n \mid 3^m-1$ so $n \leq l+2$ and then $l \geq n-2$ .

This means that $2^{n-2} \mid m$ as wanted .

Answer (score 1):

We show by induction that for any $m$ of the form $2^n q$ where $q$ is odd and $n\ge 0$, the highest power of $2$ that divides $3^{m}-1$  is $2^{n+1}$.

For the base step $n=0$, consider $3^{q}-1$. Since $3^q\equiv 3\pmod{4}$, it follows that $3^q-1$ is of the form $4t+2$, so the highest power of $2$ that divides it is $2^1$.

Now we do the induction step. Suppose that the result is true for $n=k$. We show the result is true for $n=k+1$.

Consider $3^{2^{k+1}q}-1$, where $q$ is odd. This is equal to
$$(3^{2^k q}-1)(3^{2^k q}+1).$$
By the induction hypothesis the highest power of $2$ that divides $3^{2^k q}-1$ is $2^{k+1}$. It is clear that the highest power of $2$ that divides  $3^{2^k q}+1$ is $2^1$. So the highest power of $2$ that divides $3^{2^{k+1}q}-1$ is $2^{k+2}$. This completes the induction step.